# Call SQL Server stored procedure using IBM Integration Bus ESQL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am new to IIB, trying to call SQL server stored procedure using ESQL. Could anyone share working example to call stored procedure which returns single value.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you can call a stored procedure in ESQL:

- Define a procedure with the external keyword

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac17040_.htm

- Or use the PASSTHRU statement and call the stored procedure by putting the SQL command to call it into the parameter of the statement

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05100_.htm?lang=en